# Expected =1, received=0 - why is my function not called in Angular test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, jestjs

I check console .. shownCategories is not empty , but in test is empty I am trying to check if  FilterShownCategories() is called but its out received=0, expected=1

```
it("in case edit should call filterCategories()", () => {
         component.state == 'edit';
         if (component.state == 'edit') {
           const filterCategoriesSpy = spyOn(component, 'filterCategories').and.returnValue(
             [{
               hiddenVariants: 0,
               id: 187910,
               lang: "de",
               name: "AMG/Exterieur",
               plId: 5389,
               refId: "1015001000",
               type: "AMG",
               visibleVariants: 5
             }, {
               hiddenVariants: 0,
               id: 187911,
               lang: "de",
               name: "AMG/Interieur",
               plId: 5389,
               refId: "1015002000",
               type: "AMG",
               visibleVariants: 7,
             }]);
           expect(filterCategoriesSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
         }
       });
     }}
```

This is the func :

```
  public addFirstTable() {
    console.log("addFirstTable");
    //awel mara showncategories gaya fadya a lazm amlaha lw state msh edit
    if (this.state != "compare") {
      // this.shownCategories = this.allCategories.map(a => ({ ...a }));
      this.shownCatgeories = this.FilterShownCategories();
      console.log("shownCategories if state is not compare", this.shownCategories);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
expected=1, received=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to execute function from test.

Add below line

```
component.addFirstTable();
```

before this

```
expect(filterCategoriesSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Comment: we should add this line : `var shownCategories = component.FilterShownCategories();expect(shownCategories).not.toEqual([]);`

Comment: if it's resolved your issue then please accept my answer and upvote.

Comment: Instead of `not.toEqual([])` you should check `.toEqual(...)` with given array in returnValue.

Comment: Please accept my answer if my answer was helpful to you. thanks.